# Uninitialized string offset error in simple for loop php

Tags: php

my goal is to convert every space " " in string to "%".

Here is my function:

```
<?php
$nazov = "dasa sdas da sd";
$buttonNazov = "";

for($i=0;$i<=strlen($nazov);$i++) {
  if($nazov[$i] === " ") {
     $buttonNazov .= "%"; // Line# 6
  } else {
    $buttonNazov .= $nazov[$i]; // Line#12
  }
}

echo $buttonNazov;
?>
```

I am getting output but also 2 errors:

```
( ! ) Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 15 in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 6
( ! ) Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 15 in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 12

dasa%sdas%da%sd
```

Comment: um ... `$buttonNazov = str_replace(' ', '%', $nazov);`

Comment: Offset begins at 0, not at 1; so `$i<strlen($nazov)` and not `$i<=strlen($nazov)`... and it's not a good idea to use strlen() in the `for` because it will call strlen() every iteration of the loop even though it never changes

Comment: Mark Baker your solution works thank you. I totally forgot about `str_replace` and I will stick to it thank you Christopher Morrissey.

Comment: I have just summarize both comments as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from  Mark Baker comment: `Offset begins at 0, not at 1; so $i<strlen($nazov) and not $i<=strlen($nazov)`

below is more better way of writing same

```
<?php
$nazov = "dasa sdas da sd";
$buttonNazov = "";
$len = strlen($nazov);

for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
  if("" === $nazov[$i]) {
     $buttonNazov .= "%"; 
  } else {
    $buttonNazov .= $nazov[$i]; 
  }
}
echo $buttonNazov;
?>
```

#### alternative way if you want to replace space with %

```
$buttonNazov = str_replace(' ', '%', $nazov);
```

Answer (score 0):

the last index of a string $nazov is $nazov[strlen($nazov)-1], so use < instead of <= in the loop condition:

```
for($i=0;$i<strlen($nazov);$i++)
```